# iOS) How to set refreshing view at UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, pull-to-refresh, uirefreshcontrol

I'm using UIRefreshControl to refresh data.

When I scroll upper, it refreshes data.

But I want to set refreshing view to my own custom image.

What I'm looking for is that purpule position [image]

I want to set my own image at that section.

I don't know how that position is called so I couldn't search properly.

Comment: Do you want to customise the refresh control icon image or the background image (the purple view)?

Comment: @Andrei I need circle, I just want to change purple view

Answer (score 0):

Just create an instance of `UIImageview` and add an image as a subview to the refresh controller.

```
UIImageView *imgview= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"refreshControl.png"]];
[self.refreshControl insertSubview:imgview atIndex:0];
```